# Dictionary Key as object returning KeyNotFoundError

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijkstras path finding algorithm in Unity. I have a dictionary `distances` containing  all the possible Nodes that can be walked on which is obtained from `GridData.WalkableNodes`. When trying to obtain the distance of the found neighbours for a given Node, I am not able to obtain the distance value from the `distances` dictionary for some reason. It gives me a KeyNotFoundError. Am I doing something wrong but using the Node object as the key? In my testing, you can use an Object as the key to retrieve a value from a dictionary so I do not think this is the issue.

Script files can be seen on pastebin
[GridData.cs](https://pastebin.com/Jxx5hmr8)
[Dijkstra.cs](https://pastebin.com/VytvTZu9)

```
Dictionary<Node, int> distances = GridData.WalkableCells.ToDictionary(x => x, x => int.MaxValue);

foreach (Node neighbour in neighbours)
{

    if (!visited.Contains(neighbour.Position))
    {
        int dist = distances[currentCell] + 1;

        if (dist < distances[neighbour]) // Key not found happens here!
        {
            distances[neighbour] = dist;

            priorityQueue.Enqueue(neighbour, dist);
            visited.Add(neighbour.Position);

            neighbour.parentNode = currentCell;
            parents.Add(neighbour);
        }
    }
}
```

If I use Vector3 instead of a Node as the key, it seems to work but I do not understand why it does not work when using Node.

```
Dictionary<Vector3, int> distances = GridData.WalkableCells.ToDictionary(x => x.Position, x => int.MaxValue);

foreach (Node neighbour in neighbours)
{

    if (!visited.Contains(neighbour.Position))
    {
        int dist = distances[currentNode.Position] + 1;

        if (dist < distances[neighbour.Position]) 
        {
            distances[neighbour.Position] = dist;

            priorityQueue.Enqueue(neighbour, dist);
            visited.Add(neighbour.Position);

            neighbour.parentNode = currentCell;
            parents.Add(neighbour);
        }
    }
}
```

Node class

```
public class Node
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public Node parentNode {get; set;}

public Node(Vector3 position, CellType cellType, int cost)
{
    Position = position;
    CellType = cellType;
    Cost = cost;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Node`? Does it have an equality operator?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Node is a class. I'm quite new to C#, not sure how an equality operator is implemented. I have updated the post to show the Node class.

Comment: Is Node a neighbor?

Comment: @GabrielNegut: No it doesn't. It's fine to use classes that don't override Equals and GetHashCode as dictionary keys, *if you're happy to use object identity for equality*. In this particular case, it looks like value-like-equality is required, but that's due to the way new nodes are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `new Node` to fill your hashmap and lists.

Therefore these newly crated `Node`s are o course not the **exact same instances** as the ones added into your dictionary!

It works for `Vector3` because it implements [`IEquatable<Vector3>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) and also [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode).

If you don't explicitly override `Equals` then by default [reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals) is used (see [`object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.equals))

---

You should either simply use the positions as keys since as you already figured out it already implements it. Or just make sure to implement it as well and use the position as hash code provider:

```
public class Node : IEquatable<Node>
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public Node parentNode {get; set;}

    public Node(Vector3 position, CellType cellType, int cost)
    {
        Position = position;
        CellType = cellType;
        Cost = cost;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Position.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Node other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((Node)obj);
    }
}
```

if you want to take the other properties like `Celltype` and `Cost` etc also into account and can have multiple nodes on the same position you can simply extend it doing e.g.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(Position, Cost, CellType);
}
```

according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have implemented into the Node class the override bool and Hash but this seems to now effect my `LocateWalkableCells` function I think because when I render all the walkable Nodes on the grid, it now is missing a chunk of them which is it previously was not. I will update the post to show this.

Comment: @Krellex sounds rather like a new issue/question to me .. I would guess the key issue for the dictionary is fixed which is the original scope of your question

Comment: It seems to work with now with the dictionary and not give me a KeyNotFoundError. The implementation of it though did cause the walkable cells to display oddly but I will post this is a separate question. Thanks for the help

Comment: The purpose of `public bool Equals(Node other)` is when I want to do something like `node1.Equals(node2)`? whereas `public override bool Equals(object obj)` is to allow something like a dictionary or a HashSet to correctly find the right object? e.g. `hashsetexample.Contains(node1)`

Comment: @Krellex more or less yes. The `public override bool Equals(object)` is let's say the "official" method that exists across each and every type in `c#` and `Dictionary` uses it for equality comparison. Not all types override it though -> these use reference equality. The `public bool Equals(Node other)` is just the implementation for the `Equatable` interface and as you say had more the purpose of you being able to compare two Nodes directly without the need for type checks and casting .. usually you would additionally also implement `==` and `!=` but I skipped it because it is not mandatory

Comment: Ah ok. I removed `public bool Equals(...)` for `Equatable` and it seems to have given me back my full grid instead of showing it in patches. But it still does not account for the nodes where there is an obstacle placed. Before a node is placed it checks if an object is already there.  A hashset contains all obstacle positions and so I perform `Obstacles.Contains(node)` I do not think this is correctly checking it. Do I need to implement something else for the HashSet to check if a given node is inside the HashSet?

Comment: I think that while `Dictionary` is based on the `Equals` the `Hashset` is based on `GetHashCode` .. as said you might want to take also other properties into account, not only the positions